# Last selected cell with checkbox is not being read correctly

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview where I am creating a checkbox column in the form load event:

```
Dim chkDownLoad As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
dgv.Columns.Add(chkDownLoad)
chkDownLoad.HeaderText = "DownLoad"
chkDownLoad.Name = "DownLoad"

dgv.Columns.Add("ApproxDate", "ApproxDate")
```

I have also tried:

```
 Dim chkDownLoad As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
 chkDownLoad.HeaderText = "DownLoad"
 chkDownLoad.Name = "DownLoad"
 dgv.Columns.Insert(0, chkDownLoad)

 dgv.Columns.Add("ApproxDate", "ApproxDate")
```

When I run the program several rows are built and none of the checkboxes are checked. I can check one or all of them and click the save button, however, the last checked box is always read as false. If I go back and select any other cell that check box that was false will become true. I have tried to write code to unselect everything but that does not work.

Below is the nightmare code I have written in attempts to debug.

```
   Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    For iR As Integer = 0 To dgv.RowCount - 1
        If dgv.Rows(iR).Cells(0).Selected = True Then
            Stop
        End If
        If dgv.Rows(iR).Cells(0).Value = True Then
            Debug.Print(iR.ToString & " " & dgv.Rows(iR).Cells(5).Value)
        End If
    Next

    For n As Integer = 0 To dgv.RowCount - 1
        If CBool(dgv.Rows(n).Cells("Download").Value) Then
            Stop
        End If
    Next

    'Dim blnChecked As Boolean = False
    'For iR As Integer = 0 To dgv.RowCount - 1
    '    If TypeOf dgv.Rows(iR).Cells(0) Is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell Then
    '        blnChecked = CType(dgv.Rows(iR).Cells(0).Value, Boolean)
    '    End If
    '    Debug.Print("Row: " & iR.ToString & " is " & blnChecked.ToString)

    '    'If dgv.Rows(iR).Cells(0).Value = True Then
    '    '    Debug.Print(iR.ToString & " " & dgv.Rows(iR).Cells(5).Value)
    '    'End If
    'Next 

End Sub
```

The code does indeed stop for the selected cell (that is checked) but the cell value is always false.... unless I unselect it!

I'm obviously doing something wrong because I cannot find anything in relation to a bug so it must be in my code. Please help!?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Firstly, why are you creating the column in code? Why not create it in the designer?

Comment: Is the grid bound?  If so, you should be binding your data source to a `BindingSource` and then binding that to the grid.  You can also add the `BindingSource` in the designer but you'll probably still bind it in code.  You should then call `EndEdit` on the `BindingSource` before using any data to ensure that any pending edit is committed.  If the grid is not bound then call `EndEdit` on the grid.

Comment: I am creating the column in code as that is how all the examples (I found) show how to do it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, thanks so much, EndEdit is what I needed to do. So easy yet so far away.....